# Dozer: Map a field to function output

Tags: java, dozer

I am using Dozer to do object Mapping. Everything works reaaly well just that I'm not able to map this particular thing.

```
<mapping>
<class-a>User</class-a>
<class-b>UAUserBean</class-b>
<field>
<a>RightLst.Right</a>
<b>Rights</b>
<a-hint>Right</a-hint>
<b-hint>UARightBean</b-hint>
</field>
<field>
<a>RightLst.NumInLst</a> 
<b>Rights.length</b> 
</field>
</mapping>

//here RightLst is an object of a class and numInLst (int prop)
//rights is an array of objects
```

what i want to do is

```
lUser.getRightLst().setNumInLst(uaUserBean.getRights().length);
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance.

---

```
User{ 
protected RightLst rightLst;
}

RightLst{
protected Integer numInLst;
protected Collection right = new ArrayList();
}

public class UAUserBean{
private UARightBean[] rights;
}
```

Comment: Let us see what your classes look like.

Comment: Just edited the post to show the classes. It is not in detail, coz otherwise it wuld be too long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
...
   <b>rights.length</b> 
</field>
```

Dozer will try to access the first position of the `rights` array and call the getter for the *length* property on an instance of **`UARightBean`** (which is the type of the array), obviously the *length* property doesn't exist in **`UARightBean`** and Dozer will throw an Exception.

I suggest to create a getter method in **`UAUserBean`** to return the length of the `rights` property, it would look like this:

```
 class UAUserBean {
        ... 
        public int getRightsLength() {
            return rights != null ? rights.length : 0;
        }       
    }
```

Mapping file:

```
<class-a>User</class-a>
<class-b>UAUserBean</class-b>
<field>
    <a>rightLst.numInLst</a> 
    <b>rightsLength</b> 
</field>
```

If you can't modify **`UAUserBean`**, your last option would be a custom converter from `UARightBean[]` to `Integer`, but it would look ugly.

Comment: i don't have the right to modify UAUserBean..
I've already implemented using custom converters... but its true its ugly..
i was just wondering if rights was a collection. Would it be possible to call its size() function to map it to the field in the User class..

Comment: You will experience the same issue with a List field.